# table json data returning undefined using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I'm stumped as to why the data in my table is returned undefined. I think I'm close.
Please check out my jsfiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON( "http://www.corsproxy.com/dvl.thomascooper.com/data/json_return.json", function( data ) {
        //static table head
        $('table.stats').append("<th>" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Date" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Brand" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Author" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Title" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Posts" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Exposure" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Engagement" + "</th>"); 
        //loop through json data
        $.each(data.data.rows,function( i, val ){
            //+1 to number each row starting at 1
            var rowNum = i + 1;
            //create table rows and cell and populate with data 
            $('table.stats').append(  "<tr>" + "<td>" + rowNum + "</td>" + "<td>" +    val.date + "</td>" +"<td>" + val.brand_id + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.author + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.title +  "</td>" + "<td>" + val.posts + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.reach + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.interaction + "</td>" + "</tr>");

        }); 
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/eLbq2wvh/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eLbq2wvh/6/

Comment: Header row could certainly do with `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each(data.data.rows,function( i, val ) {
```

Here, val is not object (Your data told me that)

[image]

So you could not access property that undefined like this: **val.date**

I think, here is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$.getJSON( "http://www.corsproxy.com/dvl.thomascooper.com/data/json_return.json", function( data ) {

    //static table head
    $('table.stats').append("<th>" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Date" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Brand" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Author" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Title" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Posts" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Exposure" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Engagement" + "</th>"); 
        //loop through json data
        $.each(data.data.rows,function( i, val ){
            //+1 to number each row starting at 1
            var rowNum = i + 1;
            //create table rows and cell and populate with data 
            $('table.stats').append(  "<tr>" + "<td>" + rowNum + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[0].value + "</td>" +"<td>" + val[1].value + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[2] + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[3].label +  "</td>" + "<td>" + val[4].values[0] + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[5].values[0] + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[6].values[0] + "</td>" + "</tr>");

        }); 
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the returned json - rows is an array of arrays not an array of objects.. You failed to take this into consideration.

```
$.each(data.data.rows[0],function( i, val ){
```

Also you are trying to access the value of the data by its value instead of by its key.

```
"<td>" + val.field + "</td>" +"<td>" + val.type + "</td>"
```

Checkout this [jsbin for example](http://jsbin.com/yuyesakozu/1/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference the data as if it were:
rows: [ { date: '', brand_id: '', author: '', etc }, next set of fields]

What you are actually getting is:

rows: [ [ object with field data, object with field data, etc], another array of field data objects, etc]

Here is a beginning to a script that will be flexible in how things will be returned. I've left out many of the cases you'll need to deal with:

```
    //loop through json data
    $.each(data.data.rows,function( i, val ){
        //+1 to number each row starting at 1
        var rowNum = i + 1, fields = {};

        // Find fields
        $.each(val, function(j, fieldData) {
            if(typeof fieldData == 'string') {
                fields.author = fieldData;
            } else if(fieldData.field == 'title') {
                fields.title = fieldData.label;
            } else {
                fields[fieldData.field] = fieldData.value;
            }
        });

        //create table rows and cell and populate with data 
        $('table.stats').append(  "<tr>" + "<td>" + rowNum + "</td>" + "<td>" + fields.date + "</td>" +"<td>" + fields.brand_id + "</td>" + "<td>" + fields.author + "</td>" + "<td>" + fields.title +  "</td>" + "<td>" + fields.posts + "</td>" + "<td>" + fields.reach + "</td>" + "<td>" + fields.interaction + "</td>" + "</tr>");

    });
```